# linked list with data in null node

Tags: c++, linked-list

i want to make a linked list ..

but the first node with a data and null link

if i input a string (123)
linked list be like this:

1/null - 2/point to the last one(1) - 3/point to the last one(2)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct link
{
  int data;
  link* next;
};
class LinkedList
{
private:
  link* first;
public:
  LinkedList(){}
  void Add(string s)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i > s.length(); i++)
    {
      if (i == 0)
      {
        first->data = s[i];
        first->next = NULL;
      }
      else
      {
        link* NewOne = new link;
        NewOne->data = s[i];
        NewOne->next = first;
        first = NewOne;
      }


    }

  }
  void display()
  {
    cout << first->data;
  }


};
int main()
{
  LinkedList l1;
  l1.Add("2734");
  l1.display();

  return 0;
}
```

what's the wrong in the code

Answer (score 1):

You forget to allocate memory for `first`.

Following may help (using `std::unique_ptr` for free/correct memory management):

```
struct link{
    char data;
    std::unique_ptr<link> next;
};

class LinkedList {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<link> first;
public:

void Set(const std::string& s){

    for (auto c : s) {
        std::unique_ptr<link> node = std::move(first);
        first = std::make_unique<link>();
        first->data = c;
        first->next = std::move(node);
    }
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/ZPLdXb)

Answer (score 1):

It also looks like you're storing characters in an int. Your output will be the ASCII value of the character rather than the raw int values.

I would recommend using unique pointers as Jarod42 has done. Having said that, this quick example below does not use them so you will need to call delete appropriately or use unique_ptr.

I added a last pointer to help traversal of the list as we make new links.

```
private:
Link * first;
Link *last;
int numLinks;

public:
LinkedList()
{
  first = NULL;
  last = NULL;
  numLinks = 0;
}
```

Now for Add

```
void Add(string s)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
   {
      if (numLinks == 0)
      {
         first = new Link;
         first->data = (s[i] - '0');
         first->next = NULL;

         last = first;
         numLinks++;
      }
      else
      {
         Link * newLink = new Link;
         newLink->data = (s[i] - '0');
         newLink->next = NULL;

         last->next = newLink;
         last = newLink;
         numLinks++;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor does not initialize the `first` member. Subsequently, in `Add()`:

```
for (int i = 0; i > s.length();i++){
    if (i == 0){
       first->data = s[i];
     first->next = NULL;
    }
```

This ends up dereferencing an uninitialized pointer, leading to undefined behavior.

There's also a problem with your `display()` too, but this is the main problem.

Comment: if i initialized first 
by some way like this 
    LinkedList(){
               first->data= 0;
               first->next = Null;
        }
or 
    LinkedList(){
               first->next= NULL;
        }
or 
it still  give me error .. so how can i fixed it ?!

Comment: In both of those cases 'first' is still not initialized. Try something like LinkedList() { first = new Link; }
Make sure to call delete once you're done

Comment: You need to understand the difference between initializing `first` itself, and initializing the contents of what `first` points to. The problem is not that the contents of what `first` points to is not initialized, `first` itself is not initialized.